# MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/ "uname,

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on an ecommmerce site  with python mysql and django. During login I'm getting `MultiValueDictKeyError` at /login/. Can someone review this?

This is my login page, error occurs on the name "uname":

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <center>
        <form action="/login/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="username"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">

        </form>
    </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my views.py using POST method:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from . models import *



    def home(request):
        return render(request,'index.html')

    def fn_login(request):
        v_username = request.POST['uname']
        v_password = request.POST['pass']
        try:
            login_obj = Login.objects.get(username=v_username,password=v_password)

            if login_obj.password == v_password:
                return render(request,'index.html')
            return HttpResponse('incorrect password')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return HttpResponse('invalid username')
```

This is myapp urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path 

# importing views from views..py 
from .import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('index/',views.home),
    path('login/',views.fn_login,),

]
```

my error is like this  :

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/
'uname'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'uname'
Exception Location: /home/akshay/Desktop/Django/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 78
Python Executable:  /home/akshay/Desktop/Django/env1/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/home/akshay/Desktop/Django/Ekart',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/akshay/Desktop/Django/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 25 Mar 2020 14:22:15 +0000
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you please add the full text of your error message?  That said, why are you building your own Login module (that's very insecure) instead of using the built-in auth classes?

Comment: im getting MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/ .

Comment: can i use built in auth classes for mysql rather than sqlite? cz....when i use auth class with mysql database with class models i cant authenticate...

Comment: minor text adjustments

Comment: can you please... justify...

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing

```
v_username = request.POST['uname']
v_password = request.POST['pass']
```

to this below

```
v_username = request.POST.get('uname')
v_password = request.POST.get('pass')
```

Comment: now the error is gone but the...if statement are not working...when i run its only returning   "invalid username" is there any problem with if statement... in views.py

Comment: your actual question had been answered, and had been solved. For this please open a different question. I might try answering your other question. Thank you

Comment: you can share the link here. and please dont forget to upvote. Thank you